# fig.canvas.draw() changes axis limits

Tags: matplotlib

I was stumbled by this crazy matplotlib behavior.
I am using an axis with fixed aspect ratio and the xlimits I'm imposing apparently are not respected by matplotlib.

the snippet of code goes like;

```
self.ax.axes.set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')

print("setting lower limit to : {}".format(self.lower_xlim))
self.ax.set_xlim(*self.lower_xlim)

self.fig.canvas.draw()
print("current limits are {}".format(self.an_ax.get_xlim()))
```

And this is the surprising result before and after fig.canvas.draw()

```
setting upper limit to : (27.308915605285073, 5.034483990001178)
current limits are (34.67169979764313, -2.328300202356875)
```

Is there a way to fix this ?

Comment: Hard to know without a minimal complete example.  You could have all sorts of other settings bay would cause this.

Comment: Understandable, setting both y and x limits doesnt work as well. and setting up both limits at once using ax.set() doesnt work as well. My code is too long to be added in here. Ill try ot come up with a small script to demonstrate this.  I think the question pretty much boils down to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72558709/matplotlib-set-aspectequal-datalim-while-keeping-one-axis-datalim-fixed

Comment: If you use datalim it adjusts the x or y limits to get the desired aspect ratio.  If you choose box, it adjusts the size of the frame and keeps the limits the same